# How to display thousands of records?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance

Hi
Let's say that I've to list thousands of records for my client.
How should I implement this? Some say that I have to retrieve just 300 or 400 records from the database and show those to the client. But I think there will be some problem with pagination. If I get all records from the database then I will have a performance problem. Some say to implement our own store procedure. How should I do this?

Thanks

Comment: WinForms, Web Forms, XAML... what's your UI?

Comment: What leads you to believe there will be a problem with pagination?  How do you know you'll have a performance problem if you don't use paging?  Whether or not you use a stored procedure is up to you, it has no effect on whether you can or cannot put thousands of records on the wire at one time.  I suggest moving away from considering what "some say" and look at the actual requirements of your current project.  What are they?

Comment: You can either show a few dozen/hundred/thousand records at a time on the client, or you could load the whole lot at once. If you want to give the illusion of better performance, load the first hundred or so initially, then get a background thread to fetch the rest of the records (possibly in several iterations) and update the list, while the user can already see some of the results.

Comment: @paul >> mine is Web Forms  !!

Comment: @pete >> I'v to list the music songs for my client . Those songs may reach as many as 200,000.

Comment: I assume that you'll be using a grid. Bounds grids, including the one included with Visual Studio, have nice pagination support built in. Do not reinvent the wheel on this!

Comment: @paul >> you mean I should get all the records from the database and bind with the gridview?

Comment: @kevin: You just bind to a provider. Don't worry about the paging. They'll be taken care of for you. Just try it in a separate project, you'll see. It'll take 5 minutes.

Comment: @paul >> What do you mean __bind to a provider__ ? I don't understand. Sorry I'm just a jr programmer. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to use paging and not retrieve all the records at once, I recommend using some ORM tool to abstract the complexity of the required query for paging, if using LINQ it would be something very simple: ...Skip((pageNo-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize)

Comment: >> I don't know LINQ. I'm just using Typed DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

I am in favor of sending ~100 records with the page, paginating through them by JavaScript, and retrieving further records in a batch by some higher number, say, 1000, when user navigates to unloaded data. All with no-script fallback links if you can't force user's to use JavaScript.

(Not sure how easy this is with C# frameworks; with Java's Wicket, this is quite easy.)

Answer (score 1):

Paginate the records ! That will the the only solution (which you haven't yet tried by the way!). You could add Button controls to move between pages, and data loaded to a page when the page is loaded. Or the records could be loaded all at once and stored by the app, and just shown to the user when a page is shown.

Comment: my record may hit as many as __200,000__ at last . So I think I should not load all at once. What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Paging is definitely an answer to this. However - Do all your match inside SQL Stored Proc.. Instead of depending on the GridView default paging...

If you don't want to use Paging (some clients are very adamant to show all records) then you can use Scroll event to fetch records on the fly. If you using a Web Application, you can use Ajax Call to fetch next set of records by passing the pageNo,pagesize etc....